# Where to publish (potential) Aurelia plugins to get feedback

Tags: aurelia

I've been working on an Aurelia datagrid component, and I think it might be useful to others. It has a pretty clear API and some features I haven't found in other Aurelia datagrids so far.

I'm considering making it in to a plugin and publishing it. But before I put in a lot of time, I want to gauge the level of interest in it.

What would be a good place to publish my code to get some feedback, and see if it's worth the effort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

- [Aurelia Gitter Channel](https://gitter.im/aurelia/Discuss)
- [Aurelia Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/aureliajs)